# GoogleMap : Zoom In And Zoom Out not working android app

Tags: android, google-maps, zooming

I am working on an android game where i have to draw rectangle yard [Football ground]. I draw rectangle on google map using polygon. Code is here:

```
    PolygonOptions polygonOptions =  new PolygonOptions()
            .add(new LatLng(bounds.northeast.latitude, bounds.northeast.longitude))
            .add(new LatLng(bounds.southwest.latitude, bounds.northeast.longitude))
            .add(new LatLng(bounds.southwest.latitude, bounds.southwest.longitude))
            .add(new LatLng(bounds.northeast.latitude, bounds.southwest.longitude))
            .strokeColor(color);
    mMap.addPolygon(polygonOptions);
```

I tried various code for google map zoom in :

Code 1:

```
 map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
```

Code 2 :

```
 CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(new LatLng(Latitude, Longitude))      // Sets the center of the map to Mountain View
            .zoom(30)                   // Sets the zoom
            .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
            .tilt(30)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
            .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

Code 3 :

```
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
```

None of the code works for me. Any help is most welcome!!!

Comment: Zoom level of `20` is already a `Buildings` level. Try getting `float map.getMaxZoomLevel()` before zooming in.

Comment: @foxanna i tried maximum zoom level but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

you can add zoom control(buttons) to UI with:

```
map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
```